# error in make check of pkg-config of lfs 6.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-from-scratch

I am building LFS based on LFS 6.5 book,in my ubuntu 11.10. I got test suite failed message when installing pkg-config in chapter 6.17. The error is in file pkg-config-0.23/check/common line number 20, syntax error near unexpected token ). No such problem is reported before. I am really stuck in this section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem in a test script. You can try one of the following:

1. leave out the step "make check" from the instructions and continue with "make install".
2. use a newer version of the pkg-config package (go to the "stable" version of lfs and get the pkg-config package from the instructions there.

BTW: Why are you using LFS 6.5? The current stable version is [LFS 7.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/).

Comment: even though i got that test cases failed,i proceeded to the next step and pkg-config installed without errors.the latest versions does not include pkg-config.i am a newbie in lfs.this is my first time.i will try 7.2 later.now with util-linux installation i got the following errors        /bin/sh: command substitution: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/sh: command substitution: line 4: `readlink /usr/lib/libuuid.so)'
make[5]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/sources/util-linux-ng-2.16/shlibs/uuid/src

Comment: hmmm, this looks as if something else is broken in your system. Can you spot in which file the syntax error occurs? And lfs 7.2 does contain pkg-config: see http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/pkg-config.html .